# How to "load" a file only once in scheme r5rs?

Tags: scheme, r5rs

*Is there a way to make sure that a scheme file (R5RS) is `load`ed only once?*

That is, if `foo.scm` is loaded multiple times in `bar.scm` (directly or indirectly), make sure the content of `foo.scm` is only loaded the first time.

In C++, one can enclose the whole content of a source file in `#ifndef` like this to avoid repeated imports:

```cpp
#ifndef _some_tag 
#define _some_tag

//...

#endif
```

*Is there a similar way to ensure that an old R5RS file `load`s only once in a REPL session?*

-- Clarification --

Thanks for the answers and comments so far, which suggest that there is no portable way of loading a file only once in R5RS.

Just to state the motivation, I was playing with [the little prover code](https://github.com/the-little-prover/j-bob/), which is R5RS. I found that loading its file j-bob.scm twice makes the REPL extremely slow. As pointed out in [this bug/issue report](https://github.com/the-little-prover/j-bob/issues/1), this is because j-bob redefines basic scheme keywords. Someone in that bug report suggested that a proper solution is to use r7rs (or r6rs) modules. Nonetheless, I was curious if this can be handled in r5rs. Hence this question.

Comment: 1. I started scheme about 1 1/2 year ago and sticked to R5RS as well. Mostlikely your implementation supports a newer RxRS. R5RS is from February 1998. Once you need more advance features like this or dynamic scoping; I would recommend leaving R5RS behind.
2. There is not a standard way to archive this, if you want to rely on the syntax of `(load`. Maybe you could live with an designated syntax across all dependent files and users? // edit: typo

Comment: -- clarification --
If you load a file multiple times, it will execute the top-level scope mupltiple times. This will result in rebinding all top-level bindings declared and reevaluate expressions on the scope. You can redefine things in-between. Redefining basic scheme keywords isn't a problem. Are you aware what you are about to execute? >:-)

Comment: @Tomes I encountered the same problem as said in the bug report. If I load the j-bob files  twice, and call `(atom '())` in the REPL, it hangs. If I only load the j-bob files once, then everything is fine.

Comment: This bug should be filed as a dedicated bug report so that author/contributors can support. I do not have the required runtimes to test this on my own. Once he has redefined basic scheme syntax but uses the language defaults within other macros, these syntax transformation may fail obv. Maybe the author only supports the use case of loading the required files once and then call the functions from `little-prover.scm` manually from within the REPL. The references literature could elaborate. Repository does prompt that racket has it in a dedicated package. Can't help with that either, sorry.